# Read cout and write to cin of a process with boost::process

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, io

I'm trying to spawn a shell and read the stdout and stderr, and let the user run commands by writing to stdin. I can't seem to read from stdout or stderr, and writing to stdin also apparently doesn't do anything.

If I don't try redirecting any of stdin, stdout, or stderr, it spawns a normal shell like I'd expect. However, redirecting them just makes everything vanish. The `>>` just hangs mysteriously. I pull from the child's stdout and just put it right back into the actual stdout, so I'd expect at lease something like my username to show up, but like I said, it just blocks because there must be nothing in the buffer.

```cpp
boost::process::child shell;
boost::process::opstream instream;
boost::process::ipstream errstream;
boost::process::ipstream outstream;

void console_out_read()
{
    char ch;
    do
    {
        outstream >> ch;
        std::cout << ch;
    }
    while(true);
}

void console_err_read()
{
    char ch;
    do
    {
        errstream >> ch;
        std::cerr << ch;
    }
    while(true);
}

void console_in_write()
{
    int ch;
    do
    {
        std::cin >> ch;
        instream << ch;
    }
    while(true);
}

int main()
{
    std::error_code ec;

    shell = boost::process::child("bash",
        boost::process::std_out > outstream,
        boost::process::std_err > errstream,
        boost::process::std_in < instream,
        ec);

    boost::thread cro(console_out_read);
    boost::thread cre(console_err_read);
    boost::thread cwi(console_in_write);
    shell.wait();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `console_out_read` never does anything with `ch` and never returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with the code you posted.

First, in `console_in_write` you declared `ch` to be an `int` instead of a `char`.  That means that `std::cin` will only accept things that look like numbers for it.  This leads to `std::cin` getting into an error state if you enter anything but a number.

Second, even after changing `ch` to be a `char`, `std::cin >> ch` will never read a newline character because the formatted input operations discard whitespace.  The easiest solution to this problem would be to use `std::getline` to read line-by-line instead of char-by-char and just write a newline after each line you read.

Third, boost's pipe streams are fully-buffered.  That means that you need to flush the stream after you write a newline so that the data gets send to your child process.  Otherwise you'll type a command and nothing will happen because the data is just sitting in the stream's buffer.

Fourth, `std::thread`s must be `join`ed or `detach`ed before they go out of scope.  Since you don't currently do so with your I/O threads, as soon as your subprocess exits the parent will crash.

Putting these all together, I would expect a minimal example to look something like this:

```
boost::process::child shell;
boost::process::opstream instream;
boost::process::ipstream errstream;
boost::process::ipstream outstream;

void console_out_read()
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(outstream, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
}

void console_err_read()
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(errstream, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
}

void console_in_write()
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        instream << line << std::endl;
        if (line == "exit") return;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::error_code ec;

    shell = boost::process::child("bash",
        boost::process::std_out > outstream,
        boost::process::std_err > errstream,
        boost::process::std_in < instream,
        ec);

    std::thread cro(console_out_read);
    std::thread cre(console_err_read);
    std::thread cwi(console_in_write);
    shell.wait();
    cro.join();
    cre.join();
    cwi.join();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make them unbuffered or flush without writing a newline, like in c?

Comment: You could pass a `boost::process::pipe` instead of a `pstream` if you want raw unbuffered pipe I/O.